# Import content from different CMS into episerver database

Tags: content-management-system, episerver

I am working on migrating a legacy CMS onto EPiServer CMS. I want to move the content from legacy CMS into EPiServer's database. Anyone ran into a scenario like this? I followed their document on world.episerver.com, but it is not very clear. It says to configure EPiServer site under config tab in Admin section to define Content Channel. But they do not talk about exactly what APIs to use and how different fields map in their database to EpiServer's database. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should not copy directly into the database since it is extremely difficult to get it right.
You need to start by building up your content types inside your project and then I think the easiest way to import the content would to build scheduled task or extend the admin interface with a import page.
In that you do your own mapping since you are the only one that knows what the things in the old CMS should be in EPiServer.

This is not an easy thing to do if you are new to EPiServer and I think that it might be the quickest way to contact expert services and they will then help end guide you.

Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

You can add page programmatically using EpiServer's IContenntRepository and IContentTypeRepositoiry as follows:

```
using EPiServer.Core;
using EPiServer.DataAbstraction;
using EPiServer.DataAnnotations;
using EPiServer.ServiceLocation;

PageReference parent = PageReference.RootPage;

IContentRepository contentRepository = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentRepository>();
IContentTypeRepository contentTypeRepository = EPiServer.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentTypeRepository>();

PageData myPage = contentRepository.GetDefault<PageData>(parent, contentTypeRepository.Load("StandardPage").ID);

StandardPage standardPage = contentRepository.GetDefault<StandardPage>(parent);

myPage.Property["PageName"].Value = "Name";
myPage.Property["MainBody"].Value = "My Page";
myPage.Property["PageTypeName"].Value = "Standard Page";
myPage.Property["PagePendingPublish"].Value = true;

myPage.URLSegment = EPiServer.Web.UrlSegment.CreateUrlSegment(myPage);                    

contentRepository.Save(myPage, EPiServer.DataAccess.SaveAction.Publish, EPiServer.Security.AccessLevel.NoAccess);
```